# Ajax Sending First Blank Data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

This part of my code is where I think the problem is at:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">

matches = google.contentmatch.getContentMatches();
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var messageid
        for(var match in matches)
        {
            for(var key in matches[match])
            {
                if(key == 'message_id')
                {
                    messageid = matches[match][key];
                }

            }
        }




        var name = "Email Test";
        var url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/' + messageid;
        var encodedurl = encodeURIComponent(url);
        var dataValues = "name=" + name + "&url=" + encodedurl;
        $('#crmbtn').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data: dataValues,
                url: 'http://someurl',
                success: function(){
                     alert('Sent To CRM')
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
gadgets.window.adjustHeight(50);
</script>

    <form id="myForm">
        <input type='button'  name='submit' id='crmbtn' value='Send To CRM' />
    </form>
```

The issue is that my code does what I want it to do, but instead of sending my data once it first sends blank data to my other php page and then sends the correct data afterwards. Im guessing its the way I coded my ajax function.

Comment: Could we see more of your code? Currently I can't see what could be wrong with it.

Comment: Yeah sure give me a sec.

Comment: Always end your statements using semicolons and always check `hasOwnProperty` when iterating over objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `encodeURIComponent` the `name` parameter as well:

```
var name = encodeURIComponent("Email Test");
…
var dataValues = "name=" + name + "&url=" + encodedurl;
```

Moreover, it's better to bind that event to your form's `submit` handler and prevent *that* action, like:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='crmbtn' value='Send To CRM' />
</form>
```

(changed `type` to `submit`) and

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(){ …
```

And when you're iterating over objects, always check `hasOwnProperty`:

```
for(var match in matches)
{
    if (matches.hasOwnProperty(match)) {
        …
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a wild guess (I need to see more of the code...), but if `#crmbtn` is a link, you need to change:

```
$('#crmbtn').click(function(){
```

to:

```
$('#crmbtn').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

To prevent opening the linked page.

**Edit:** Based on your update, I would think that is the problem, you might be submitting the form and without an `action` attribute, the form submits to itself.

Comment: Your answer has been obsoleted already by the OP's addition. ;) Moreover, jQuery normalizes `return false`, so your correction not necessary.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel I noticed and updated, it does seem to be the problem after all.

Comment: And no, the default type for a button is not `submit`. Moreover, it's an `input` element with *type* button, only if it was `submit` it would submit the form by default.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel I´m not sure if `return false` on a click on an ID prevents the form submit.

Comment: Now I'm thinking of it: that may be true. I think the OP needs to prevent the `form` from submitting.

Comment: yeah I believe you guys are right about the form submitting. Bare with me Im going to try coding the right solution right now.